# PowerBI visualisation - connecting sharepoint excel data to powerBI

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to connect the organization's live excel data from SharePoint to PowerBI.
The SharePoint data is in Excel sheets individually stored in subfolders.
I need all subfolders of excel data to make master excel, connect and visualize in powerbi.

[image]

I tried connecting subfolder Excels into one excel sheet, but it gave an error after the 14th sheet in that excel. It says Excel Ram issue.

How can we make master excel from SharePoint subfolder excel sheets and connect to power bi?

Comment: Post your code, so we can see what you did.

Comment: Have you considered skipping the "master Excel sheet" and using only Power BI to aggregate the spreadsheets in the subfolders? Power Query is AMAZING at doing this. One reason you might not have discovered this is you need to start with the Sharepoint Folder data connector. Here's an article from Microsoft 

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/combining-excel-files-hosted-on-a-sharepoint-folder/